# What does the expression int(2.5) produce?

Tags: python-3.x

Does it equate to any of the following, eg. 72 or "72"?

Have tried typing the expression in python but to no avail.

Comment: Why don't you just run it? What do you mean by "Have tried typing the expression in python but to no avail."

Comment: First before you ask any python question, you need to learn how to open python, close python, print things on the screen, etc.. the very basic ones. You can google these. Then afterwards you can ask questions related to what you are trying to do. How can we be of help if in the first place you do not know how to print anything on the screen? We can only help in solving an issue or when you do not get what you expect

Comment: This question is liable to be put on hold and downvoted since it is clearly not useful. The result is an **int**.

Answer (score 1):

int(2.5) will convert 2.5 to an integer, so the output will be 2.

You can test it yourself by starting python3 in a shell, and then typing int(2.5)